# Stack Overflow UI Translation via Greasemonkey

Tags: script, localisation

### What is it?

**Why this project?**

Every so often, somebody asks on meta "can we allow foreign language contributions to StackOverflow" and a huge debate ensues. However, once upon a time, somebody observed that in fact no matter which way you look at it the StackExchange UI is in English, and that would be the first translation requirement.

**Why GreaseMonkey?**

I'm not a StackExchange Inc employee and this isn't an official effort. So I've used GreaseMonkey so the translation is relative to me, and jQuery to get cheap upvotes. An advantage of this approach is that it provides Jeff & Co with exact locations of text that needs to be translated and the translated string.

This is basically a rudimentary method of crowd-sourcing translations until an official way of doing that exists.

**What works?**

Translation of a fair few elements.

**What doesn't work?**

A lot of things. The translation effort isn't complete. I can't control the sizing of divs (well I can, but that's out of scope), nor can I easily do things like right to left or sophisticated date/time localisation.

**What could be improved?**

My French. My Javascript. More languages. More translation. This is a very early stage project and French is not my native language. Input from Native French speakers always appreciated. Likewise, submission of extra translated parts and the whole thing in other languages would greatly help.

**I would like to submit an improvement!**

Feel free. If you would like to add a language, please copy the script, do the translations using your new script and send them to me and/or fork the repository and I'll pull them in.

**Where can I get the source?**

Here: https://github.com/ninefingers/so-translation

**License?**

http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ or at your option whatever license StackOverflow is using.

**I want to contact you!**

See my profile, or even better reply here.

### Where can I get it?

Currently available languages:

- [French](https://github.com/ninefingers/so-translation/raw/master/stack_overflow_french.user.js) (v0.1).

Comment: @George thanks, there's a few bugs at present (it breaks the user profile slightly...) hopefully I can iron these out next week along with more translations.

Comment: [Follow-up on Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/105169/help-translate-the-stackexchange-ui-unofficial)

Comment: see also http://stackapps.com/questions/2978/japanese-stack-exchange-localization for a Japanese localization