# Japanese stack exchange localization

Tags: script, localisation, japanese

### Screenshot

[image: JLU Main Page]

### About

This script was originally created for the JLU (Japanese Language and Usage) site as part of the [Creating as much Japanese interface as possible to be more inclusive of native Japanese speakers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/creating-as-much-japanese-interface-as-possible-to-be-more-inclusive-of-native-j) meta page, but it now should work on all the major Stack Exchange sites.

To change to Japanese, click the `日本語版` icon which will appear in the top right corner of every page.

It's a work in progress, but a fairly large amount of the site has been translated including UI elements, tooltips, dates, some messages, Stack Exchange badges+descriptions, tags on the JLU site etc. For the current status, please see the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/cyphr/Stack-Exchange-Japanese-Localization).

I'm not a Japanese native speaker and there are probably lots of errors remaining. If anyone could give any assistance correcting or contributing to the translation I'd much appreciate it (many thanks to @ento for checking some of the translations!)

#### License

[Creative Commons CC0 1.0](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) (Public Domain Dedication), so that the translations may be reused if an official Stack Exchange localization gets done etc.

#### Download

- Download from: https://github.com/cyphr/Stack-Exchange-Japanese-Localization/raw/master/jlu_localize.user.js
- How to install this user script: https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

#### Platform

The platforms I'm currently testing it on are Firefox 16.0.1 with Greasemonkey and Chromium "20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 (144678)". I hope to support IE, Safari and Opera one of these days too.

### Contact

Please leave a comment or post an answer here and I'll try to respond as quickly as possible.

### Code

It uses jQuery/JavaScript.

The source code can be viewed at https://github.com/cyphr/Stack-Exchange-Japanese-Localization.